# Consistent Android Geofence Monitoring

Tags: android, android-geofence

I've implemented some geofences into an app and have been testing them using mock locations on my test device (Samsung S4 running Android 5.0.1). While using mock locations, the transition detection has been working 100% of the time. I've now moved onto other Android devices and put the app on some phones which frequently (physically) enter and leave the geofence location, and I've noticed that the detection OFTEN doesn't work. This is really inconvenient so I was hoping there would be some way to make the detection more consistent.

My code which calls the geofence to be created:

```
private void startGeofenceMonitoring() {
    Log.d(TAG, "startGeofenceMonitoring called");
    try {
        Geofence geofence = new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId(GEOFENCE_ID)
                .setCircularRegion(51.364516, -0.189643, 150)
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                .setNotificationResponsiveness(1000)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                .build();

        GeofencingRequest geofencingRequest = new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
                .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER | GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT)
                .addGeofence(geofence)
                .build();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        if (!googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "GoogleApiClient is not connected");
        } else {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION);

                return;
            }
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(googleApiClient, geofencingRequest, pendingIntent)
                    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                            if (status.isSuccess()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Successfully added Geofence");
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Failed to add geofence - " + status.getStatus());
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SecurityException - " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

GeofenceService.java:

```
public class GeofenceService extends IntentService {

public static final String TAG = "GeofenceService";

DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

public GeofenceService() {
    super(TAG);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    GeofencingEvent event = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    if (event.hasError()) {
        //TODO:
    } else {

        double longitude = 0;
        double latitude = 0;

        int transition = event.getGeofenceTransition();
        List<Geofence> geofences = event.getTriggeringGeofences();
        Geofence geofence = geofences.get(0);
        String requestID = geofence.getRequestId();

        longitude = event.getTriggeringLocation().getLongitude();
        latitude = event.getTriggeringLocation().getLatitude();

        final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        if (longitude != 0 && latitude != 0) {

            if (transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Entering geofence - " + requestID);

                //My on enter code

            } else if (transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Exited geofence - " + requestID);
                //My on exit code
            }
        } else {

            mRootRef.child("users/" + user.getUid() + "/error").setValue("lat/long = 0");

        }
    }
}
```

I've seen online that say using a broadcast receiver works better than what I've done but embarrassingly, I'm not quite good enough to really understand how to convert what I have done to what others have suggested.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

check out this answer there is an implementation of broadcast receiver with geofence

[Android Geofencing Notifications when app is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42037155/android-geofencing-notifications-when-app-is-closed/42640598#42640598)